# What happens when I use System.Threading.Timer with TimerTrigger?

Tags: azure, timer, azure-functions

currently me and my team are writing a test function, which calls a method from our SDK every 5 minutes. SDK initializes a `System.Threading.Timer` on its own, which then performs some action with defined interval.

Now - what happens with SDK's timer if a function is not called within a lifetime of our function? Is it going to be executed anyway or maybe it is going to be killed at some point?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are on Consumption Plan, the Function App will go idle 5 minutes after the last call, so your `Timer` will get recycled. If it's within 5 minutes, the timer will get called.

However, this idea seems very fishy to me. This doesn't seem like intended usage of Azure Functions.

Comment: It's worth keeping in mind that we've relaxed the timeout a bit and you can now go up to 10 minutes. The default in the host.json still sets it at 5, so the default behavior hasn't changed, but you can now go up to 10 minutes for timeouts and the idle time will also respect that.